# Show that the following is true: $a_j = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-z_0| = r} f(z) (z-z_0)^{-j-1}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n$ have a radius of convergence of $R>0$. Show that the following is true:

$$a_j = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-z_0| = r} f(z) (z-z_0)^{-j-1}dz$$

My Proof goes as follows: Place the sum in the integral, and interchange the sum and integral:

$$a_j = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-z_0| = r} f(z) (z-z_0)^{-j-1}dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{|z-z_0| = r}  a_n (z-z_0)^{n-j-1}dz$$

Three causes can occur if $n = j$, then the integral becomes (by cauchy formula)

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0| = r}  a_n (z-z_0)^{-1}dz = 1$$

If $n > j$, then the integral is (for some positive integer $k$)

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0| = r}  a_n (z-z_0)^{k}dz = 0$$

By the Cauchy theorem, which says a closed curve that is analytic inside must be zero. I am having trouble dealing with the last case where $n < j$. We will get a negative factor $\int (z-z_0)^{-k}$, and its not obvious why this should go to zero. Can someone help complete this line of logic?

Comment: Compute the integral using the definition of the line integral. It's over a circle, which you can parameterize by $z(t) = z_0 + re^{it}$.

Comment: Minor pedantic point, you need $r < R$.